# how can I find the path of consecutive numbers in a file with python?

Tags: python, algorithm, path, numbers, conditional-statements

I have a file of  4000,000 data. I'm starting programming in python. I want to find a path to arrive of 7 to 1. But I have some conditionals:

1.- The path must be descending for example: 7, 6, 5....1 (hoping to be consecutive), but can be 7,6,3,1. The principal goal is descending (second column). Imagine that the substrate between lines must be = 1 to identify them

2.- The path mustn't go up. For example: If i'm in 7, 6, 5..and then 6 is not correct. The next number of 5 must be the number 4, or other lower but no higer. I Imagine that the substrate between lines must be -1 to identify them

3.- Could reapeat the numbers. For example if i'm in 7 , I could have some lines in 7 before to pass 6 and it would be ok. Remember, the principal goal is no go up, is descending. I imagine the result will be constant 0 or 1 .

4.- If one of this conditionals are false, so: 
a) start again but no in the first line where is a 7. I mean, start in the next line where is a 7 (second 7 in the file)
if there is not a path starting in 7, take then line with 6, and so on, until to find the path to arrive to 1.
b) or start from the last line where the process is broken. (I don't know if this option is eficient)

In resume, I want to find the path eficient to go from 7 to 1, in a descending way, and don't go up.

input file is:

```
 1  6
 2  6
 3  6
 4  7
 5  7
 6  3
 7  3
 8  5
 9  7
 10 6
```

...so etc.

Out file:

```
45   7 
46   7
47   7
48   7 
49   6
50   6
51   5
52   5
53   4
54   3
55   2
56   1
```

or

```
50      7
51      6
52      5
53      4
54      3
55      2
56      1
```

So, could you guide me how can I do this process?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried to get this done?

Comment: Well, I tried to find a way easy to do this, but I don't have idea what modules of python could help me. Do you have some idea?

Comment: better to add `algorithms` tag. This will be more useful.

Comment: It is indeed an interesting question, but some of us will be reluctant to post an answer if you do not show your current research. In addition, it would be useless to post an algorithm that you already use or a less efficient one. Long story short, you should really add your current attempt.

Comment: [Longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem, if I am not mistaken (you want it decreasing, but makes no difference).

Answer (score 0):

I would create a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with a state for each number (7 states, 1 to 7). At each line:

- If the number on the current line is 7: create a new instance of the machine (it would be a class) and push it to a list of "alive" automata.
- Call `.add_number(parsed_number)` on all the machines. This function remembers the number and returns one of three possible results:

  - 0 - I don't accept the number, toss me away (you have to model all state transitions which is basically any transition from larger to smaller number).
  - 1 - I have accepted the number, do nothing.
  - 2 - I have accepted the number and the number is 1: print what I have accumulated and toss me away.